# Rust/Rocket can't compile `state` and `pear_codegen`

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm getting started with Rust and Rocket.

I'm following the instructions with the Rocket [Getting Started](https://rocket.rs/guide/quickstart/) and I'm getting "error: Could not compile `state`." The full log is here:`

> ~/.cargo/bin/cargo run
>       Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`  Downloading rocket_codegen v0.3.3  Downloading rocket v0.3.3
>   Compiling gcc v0.3.54    Compiling smallvec v0.4.4    Compiling libc
>   v0.2.34    Compiling version_check v0.1.3    Compiling language-tags
>   v0.2.2    Compiling serde v1.0.23    Compiling state v0.3.2
>   error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release
>   channel  -->
>   /Users/ktenjin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/state-0.3.2/src/lib.rs:1:1
>   | 1 | #![feature(const_fn)]   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release
>   channel  -->
>   /Users/ktenjin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/state-0.3.2/src/lib.rs:2:1
>   | 2 | #![feature(const_unsafe_cell_new)]   |
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release
>   channel  -->
>   /Users/ktenjin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/state-0.3.2/src/lib.rs:3:1
>   | 3 | #![feature(const_atomic_usize_new)]   |
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release
>   channel  -->
>   /Users/ktenjin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/state-0.3.2/src/lib.rs:4:1
>   | 4 | #![feature(const_atomic_bool_new)]   |
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> error: aborting due to 4 previous errors
>
> error: Could not compile `state`. warning: build failed, waiting for
>   other jobs to finish... error: build failed

I run it again and I got

> error: Could not compile `pear_codegen`.

How do I resolve this. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching on a Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177226/matching-on-a-box)

Comment: "Before you can start writing a Rocket application, you’ll need a **nightly** version of Rust installed."

Comment: As Stefan says, the output is pretty straightforward: `error[E0554]: #![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [rocket tutorial](https://rocket.rs/guide/quickstart/) states that you need rust nightly in order to compile it. In order to install nightly, you do as they say in [this page](https://rocket.rs/guide/getting-started/) they link in the tutorial:

1. [install rustup](https://www.rustup.rs/)
2. do `rustup default nightly`

This is all in the docs, so it should be obvious. But from my own experience I often miss those obvious things because starting with a new language is hard and you have jumped over many hurdles already and these might just have been the one hurdle which made you stumble.