# How to pattern match on `&Box<T>` without using `as_ref`

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Is there any way to pattern match on an `&Box<T>` without using `as_ref`? I'm using stable Rust, so **the answer can't involve `box_patterns`**.

Essentially, I have code like this:

```rust
enum Foo {
    Thing(Box<ThingKind>),
}

enum ThingKind {
    One(Foo),
    Two(Foo, Foo),
}

fn my_function(foo: &Foo) {
    match foo {
        Foo::Thing(ThingKind::One(_inner)) => { /* ... */ }
        Foo::Thing(ThingKind::Two(_left, _right)) => { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

but the compiler doesn't like that:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:20
   |
11 |     match foo {
   |           --- this expression has type `&Foo`
12 |         Foo::Thing(ThingKind::One(_inner)) => { /* ... */ }
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found enum `ThingKind`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Box<ThingKind>`
                found enum `ThingKind`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:20
   |
11 |     match foo {
   |           --- this expression has type `&Foo`
12 |         Foo::Thing(ThingKind::One(_inner)) => { /* ... */ }
13 |         Foo::Thing(ThingKind::Two(_left, _right)) => { /* ... */ }
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Box`, found enum `ThingKind`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Box<ThingKind>`
                found enum `ThingKind`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Then I tried this instead:

```rust
enum Foo {
    Thing(Box<ThingKind>),
}

enum ThingKind {
    One(Foo),
    Two(Foo, Foo),
}

fn my_function(foo: &Foo) {
    match foo {
        Foo::Thing(kind) => match kind {
            ThingKind::One(_inner) => { /* ... */ }
            ThingKind::Two(_left, _right) => { /* ... */ }
        },
    }
}
```

but the compiler gives a similar error on that one as well.

Then I tried using `kind.as_ref()` in the inner `match`, which *does* work, but it's kind of annoying to have to add that every time. So, is there any way to do it without `as_ref`?

Comment: On nightly you can do this using [`box_patterns`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/box-patterns.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the box keyword in pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177226/how-do-i-use-the-box-keyword-in-pattern-matching)

Comment: As I said in the question, I am using stable Rust, so I can't use `box_patterns`.

Comment: Then you answered your own question. You can't use nightly/`box_patterns`, so you can't match like that then :)

Comment: I asked because I wasn't sure if there was some other way to do it that involved match ergonomics or something.

Comment: If there were some other way to do it, then `box_patterns` wouldn't need to be added.

Comment: @Aplet123 That other way could have been less ergonomic than `box_patterns`, or not support all of their usecases but work for this one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [`std::ops::Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html).

```
enum Foo {
    Thing(Box<ThingKind>),
}

enum ThingKind {
    One(Foo),
    Two(Foo, Foo),
}

impl std::ops::Deref for Foo {
    type Target = ThingKind;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        match self {
            Foo::Thing(b) => &*b,
        }
    }
}

fn my_function(foo: &Foo) {
    match &**foo {
        ThingKind::One(_inner) => { /* ... */ }
        ThingKind::Two(_left, _right) => { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. My enum has more variants than just `Thing`, so this won't work at all. Also, it's more verbose than my current code.